# Interface gps and ultrasonic sensor simultaneously

Tags: arduino-uno, gps, iot

I am able to interface  gps and the ultrasonic sensor and obtain data successfully for individual interfacing with the Arduino UNO. When I combined the code for these two, I only get the data values from gps but no measurement values are obtained for the ultrasonic sensor.In the variable data, I have stored the gps data packet. I have read the solution for the same problem but none of them worked. I have attached the code below:

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    #include "TinyGPS++.h"

    SoftwareSerial serial_connection(8, 9);

    TinyGPSPlus gps;
    TinyGPSCustom Trackingangle(gps, "GPRMC", 8);
    TinyGPSCustom Dir_NS (gps, "GPRMC", 4);
    TinyGPSCustom Dir_EW (gps, "GPRMC", 6);

    String data,tr,ew,ns,d1;
  int a=0;
    const int trigPin = 6;
    const int echoPin = 7;
    long duration;
    int distance;
    int buttonPin = 12;
    String s="",str_dist="",str_button="";
    int buttonPushCounter = 0;  
    int buttonState = 0;        
    int lastButtonState = 0;  

    void setup()
    {
      pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
      Serial.begin(9600);
            serial_connection.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop()
    {
      data="";tr="";d1="";
    serial_connection.listen();
     dat_gps();
       if(data!="")
    {
    Serial.println("GPS DATA= "+data);
    ultra();
      }
   }
        void ultra()
    {
distance=0;duration=0;
         digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    //if(duration!=0)
    {
      distance= duration*0.034/2;
        Serial.print("Distance= ");
    Serial.println(String(distance));
    }
    }

    void dat_gps()
    {
     {
      while(serial_connection.available())
      {
        gps.encode(serial_connection.read());
      }

    if (Trackingangle.isUpdated())
    {
        tr=String(Trackingangle.value()); //    Serial.println(tr);
    }
    if (Dir_EW.isUpdated())
    {

     ew=String(Dir_EW.value());  
    }
    if (Dir_NS.isUpdated())
    {

      ns=String(Dir_NS.value());  
    }
    if(tr!="")
    { if(gps.location.isUpdated())
     {       delay(2000);
        data=String(gps.satellites.value());
       data+=",";
       if(data!="0,")
       {
        data+=String(gps.location.lat(), 6);
        data+=",";
        data+=String(gps.location.lng(), 6);
        data+=",";
           data+=String(gps.speed.mph());
              String a=String(gps.altitude.feet());
         if(a!="")
       {   data+=",";
       data+=a;
         data+=",";
          data+=String(gps.hdop.value());  
         data+=",";
         data+=tr;
         data+=",";
         data+=ns;
         data+=",";
         data+=ew;
         data+="";
            }
       }}
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: You need to explain your hardware setup and your code.

What type of communication do your different devices use? I2C? SPI?

What pins do they use for their interfaces?

What model of GPS and ultrasonic sensor are you using? Where can your readers find documentation and specs on those devices? What do the different commands to the devices do?

Also, you need to fix the formatting on your code. The indentation is a mess, and makes it very hard to follow the flow.

Comment: You can't.  An Arduino Uno is a a single processor.  It can do only one thing at once.  Please can you have a go at formatting your code, because its not very reader friendly.

Comment: Put `Serial.println("GPS DATA= "+data);` right after the call to `dat_gps()` and tell us what it prints.

Comment: I am using HC SR04 as ultrasonic sensor and Quectel L80 as gps. I want serial comunication on pins 8&9.

Comment: @SimSon, some values are shown as 0 as gps takes time to set. Once  its set, all the values are printed

Comment: Can anyone help?